# PHP Regex expression excluding <pre> tag

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, replace, pre

I am using a WordPress plugin named *Acronyms* (https://wordpress.org/plugins/acronyms/). This plugin replaces acronyms with their description. It uses a  PHP *PREG_REPLACE* function.

The issue is that it replaces the acronyms contained in a `<pre>` tag, which I use to present a source code.

Could you modify this expression so that it won't replace acronyms contained inside `<pre>` tags (not only directly, but in any moment)? Is it possible?

The PHP code is:

```
$text = preg_replace(
    "|(?!<[^<>]*?)(?<![?.&])\b$acronym\b(?!:)(?![^<>]*?>)|msU"
  , "<acronym title=\"$fulltext\">$acronym</acronym>"
  , $text
);
```

Comment: Thank you collapsar for the code style!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a PCRE [SKIP/FAIL regex trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) (also works in PHP) to tell the regex engine to only match something if it is not inside some delimiters:

```
(?s)<pre[^<]*>.*?<\/pre>(*SKIP)(*F)|\b$acronym\b
```

This means: skip all substrings starting with `<pre>` and ending with `</pre>`, and only then match `$acronym` as a whole word.

See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xT8nL0/2)

Here is a [sample PHP demo](https://ideone.com/G6Q2QI):

```
<?php
$acronym = "ASCII";
$fulltext = "American Standard Code for Information Interchange";
$re = "/(?s)<pre[^<]*>.*?<\\/pre>(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b$acronym\\b/"; 
$str = "<pre>ASCII\nSometext\nMoretext</pre>More text \nASCII\nMore text<pre>More\nlines\nASCII\nlines</pre>"; 
$subst = "<acronym title=\"$fulltext\">$acronym</acronym>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
<pre>ASCII</pre><acronym title="American Standard Code for Information Interchange">ASCII</acronym><pre>ASCII</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for a one line string. What about a string which is contained in the <pre> tag but has more then one line (contains new line characters)?

Comment: OK, regex, code, links and program are updated. I tested with `[^<]*` and it did not require `(?s)` multiline flag, but I thought you could have `<` inside `<pre>`, so switched to dot, and forgot to add the flag :(

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `preg_split` and keep the code block as a group, only replace the non-code block part then combine it back as a complete string:

```
function replace($s) {
    return str_replace('"', '&quot;', $s); // do something with `$s`
}

$text = 'Your text goes here...';
$parts = preg_split('#(<\/?[-:\w]+(?:\s[^<>]+?)?>)#', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$text = "";
$x = 0;
foreach ($parts as $v) {
    if (trim($v) === "") {
        $text .= $v;
        continue;
    }
    if ($v[0] === '<' && substr($v, -1) === '>') {
        if (preg_match('#^<(\/)?(?:code|pre)(?:\s[^<>]+?)?>$#', $v, $m)) {
            $x = isset($m[1]) && $m[1] === '/' ? 0 : 1;
        }
        $text .= $v; // this is a HTML tag…
    } else {
        $text .= !$x ? replace($v) : $v; // process or skip…
    }
}

return $text;
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/mecha-cms/extend.plugin.typography/blob/e0da619b896ab46383fe1bd2b7c0adbb5252c57b/typography/engine/kernel/converter.typography.php).